# If $v,w\in T_{p}M$ then $v+w\in T_{p}M$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Definition 1:** Suppose $M$ a differentiable manifold and $p\in M$.
A funtion $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $p \in M$ iff $\exists U_p \subset M$ : $f:U_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.

**Definition 2:**$D_p =${set of all differentiable functions at $p \in M$}

**Definition 3:** Suppose $M$ a differentiable manifold and $p\in M$.
A tangent vector at $p\in M$ is an operator $v:D_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad : \quad f \mapsto v(f)$ with
i) $v(mf+ng)=mv(f)+nv(g) \quad \forall f,g \in D_p$
ii)$v(fg)=v(f)g(p)+f(p)v(g) \quad \forall f,g \in D_p$

**Definition 4:** $T_{p}M=${set of all tangent vectors at $p \in M$}

**I need to prove that**:
For $v,w \in T_{p}M$ and $k \in \mathbb{R} $ then :
i) $v+w \in T_{p}M$
ii) $kv \in T_{p}M$

I understand that this is similar to the directional derivative of a vector function.
I know that in the "direction" $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ at $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

\begin{align} \quad (\mathbf{f} + \mathbf{g})'(\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{u}) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\mathbf{f} + \mathbf{g})(\mathbf{c} + h\mathbf{u}) - (\mathbf{f} + \mathbf{g})(\mathbf{c})}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c} + h\mathbf{u}) + \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{c} + h\mathbf{u}) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}) - \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{c})}{h} \\ & \
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c} + h\mathbf{u}) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c})}{h} + \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{c} + h\mathbf{u}) - \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{c})}{h} \\ &= \mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{u}) + \mathbf{g}'(\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{u}) \end{align}

But i can't to this on a manifold.
I need a detailed proof.
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of thinking about directional derivatives, you should use your "Definition 3".  If you have two derivations $v, w: D_p \to \mathbb{R}$, how can you get another?

Comment: you mean that v+w is also a derivation ?

Comment: Do we mean that $u+v$ is also a derivation? That's exactly what "$u+v\in T_pM$" means, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a tangent vector is defined (algebraiclly) as a derivation on the $\mathbb{R}$-Algebra of germs of smooth function at $p$, So all u need to prove that the set of derivation of $D_{p}$ is closed under addition and scalar multplication.take two tangenet vectors,v and w,i.e $v,w:D_{p}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ are two derivations,now we need to prove that $v+w$ is linear,$v+w(mf+ng)=v(mf+ng)+w(mf+ng)=m(v+w)f))+n(v+w)(g)$ and that it satisfies leibniz rule,$(v+w)(fg)=v(fg)+w(fg)=v(f)g(p)+f(p)v(g)+w(f)g(p)+f(p)w(g)=(v+w)(f)\times g(p)+(v+w)(g)\times f(p)$

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't see how  $v+w \in T_{p}M $

Comment: I Proved that $v+w$ satisfies both conditions mentioned in Definition 3.think of tangent vectors in terms of the definition u were given ,that is linear maps $D_{p}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the additional condition ii (they are called deriviations),So if I want that "something is a tangent vector,I need to show that $something$ satisfies both conditions in definition 3.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u,v\colon D_p\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be two tangent vectors, then you have maps:
$$u+v\colon
D_p\rightarrow\mathbb{R},f\mapsto(u+v)(f):=u(f)+v(f)$$
$$\lambda\cdot u\colon
D_p\rightarrow\mathbb{R},f\mapsto(\lambda\cdot u)(f):=\lambda\cdot u(f).$$
You can now check, if your conditions are fulfilled. Let $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g\in D_p$. For $u+v$ you get, using its definition and then, that $u$ and $v$ are both tangent vectors:
\begin{align*}
(u+v)(mf+ng)
&=u(mf+ng)+v(mf+ng)
=mu(f)+nu(g)+mv(f)+nv(g) \\
&=m\big(u(f)+v(f)\big)
+n\big(u(g)+v(g)\big)
=m(u+v)(f)+n(u+v)(f)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
(u+v)(fg)
&=u(fg)+v(fg)
=u(f)g(p)+f(p)u(g)
+v(f)g(p)+f(p)v(g) \\
&=\big(u(f)+v(f)\big)g(p)
+f(p)\big(u(g)+v(g)\big)
=(u+v)(f)g(p)
+f(p)(u+v)(g).
\end{align*}
The case for $\lambda\cdot u$ is done totally analogous. I'll leave that to you.

---

There is also another definition of tangent vectors, which I find easier and which therefore might help you better understand them: We interpret tangent vectors as the derivatives of smooth paths at the given point, allowing us to identify them directly with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which are easier to imagine:

[image]

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold, $p\in M$ be a point and $(U,\phi)$ be a chart (a homeomorphism $\phi\colon M\supset U\rightarrow\phi(U)\subset\mathbb{H}^n:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|x_n\geq 0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$). Take two smooth curves $\gamma,\delta\colon(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\rightarrow M$ with $\gamma(p)=\delta(p)=0$, then define an equivalence relation:
$$\gamma\sim\delta
:\Leftrightarrow
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\phi\circ\gamma)\vert_{t=0}
=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\phi\circ\delta)\vert_{t=0}.$$
You can interpret the right part as that when you transfer the curves from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then their derivatives at $t=0$, which are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, are the same. The equivalence relation basically transfers that back to the curves on $M$ and therefore also transfers the new notion of tangent vectors.

The only thing that is left to be shown is, that this equivalence relation is independent of the used chart: Let $(V,\psi)$ be another chart around $p$, then using $\gamma(0)=\delta(0)=p$ as well as $\gamma\sim\delta$ for $(U,\phi)$, we get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\psi\circ\gamma)\vert_{t=0}
&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\psi\circ\phi^{-1}\circ\phi\circ\gamma)\vert_{t=0}
=\left(D(\psi\circ\phi^{-1})\circ\phi\circ\gamma\right)(0)
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\phi\circ\gamma)\vert_{t=0} \\
&=\left(D(\psi\circ\phi^{-1})\circ\phi\circ\delta\right)(0)
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\phi\circ\delta)\vert_{t=0}
=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\psi\circ\phi^{-1}\circ\phi\circ\delta)\vert_{t=0} \\
&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\psi\circ\delta)\vert_{t=0},
\end{align*}
and therefore $\gamma\sim\delta$ for $(V,\psi)$.

The tangent space can now be defined as:
\begin{equation}
T_pM
:=\{\gamma\in C^\infty((-\epsilon,\epsilon),M)|\gamma(0)=p\}/\sim.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much!!!