# Can $f:M^n \rightarrow N^m$ be an immersion if $m<n$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M,N$ be manifolds with $\dim M=n$ and $\dim N=m$.

We say $f\colon M^n \rightarrow N^m$ is an immersion if:

$$df_p\colon T_pM \rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$$
is injective. Where $p \in M$.
Can there exist an immersion if $\dim M>\dim N$?

Comment: A related linear algebra question: If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, $\dim V > \dim W$, and $T \colon V \to W$ is a linear transformation, can $T$ be injective?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang No, so the same in the case of manifolds, there can't be such an immersion ?

Comment: Compare your answer to the definition of immersion and I think you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a bit of background to the comment of Matthew Leingang:

The dimension of the tangent spaces is that of the respective manifold [due to construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4565931). So we have $\dim T_pM=\dim M=m$ and $\dim T_{f(p)}N=\dim N=n$. According to the dimension formula (basic linear algebra, hence doesn't even need knowledge about manifolds), you have:
$$
\dim\ker(\mathrm df_p)
+\underbrace{\dim\operatorname{img}(\mathrm df_p)}_{\leq n}
=\dim T_pM=m.$$
Here you can see, that if $n<m$ holds, then $\dim\ker(\mathrm df_p)\neq 0$, so the kernel can't be trivial, which [is equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193333) to $\mathrm df_p$ being injective.